# Invalid column name 'filter' error in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am getting an weird kind of error. I say weird because I don't understand why am I getting that error. I suppose there is syntax error but i don't exactly get what the error since it looks correct.

Error that I am getting is in a SQL Server Procedure that I have created. In the below procedure I am getting an error specifically in below part.

```
INSERT INTO agentids (filter, agentid)
    SELECT
         filter
        ,agentid
    FROM selected_agents sa
    WHERE sa.agentname = @p_agentname
    AND sa.agentloginid = @p_agentloginid;
```

If I remove the above **Insert Statement**, I am able to compile the procedure. I understand that filter is in-build SQL Server variable but I have used it at other places in the procedure and it executes properly if I remove the **Insert Statement** part

> Update Note: I missed mentioning this earlier, but if I execute this
>   procedure as it is "master" database it gets compiled successfully.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getAgentLogActivity] @p_agentname NVARCHAR(50),
                @p_agentloginid NVARCHAR(50), 
                @p_startTime DATETIME,
                @p_endTime DATETIME             
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @l_event_login      SMALLINT
    DECLARE @l_event_logout     SMALLINT
    DECLARE @l_eventtype            SMALLINT
    DECLARE @l_reasoncode       SMALLINT
    DECLARE @l_agentid          INT
    DECLARE @l_eventdatetime    DATETIME
    DECLARE @l_filter           BIT
    DECLARE @l_mineventdatetime     DATETIME
    DECLARE @l_maxeventdatetime     DATETIME
    DECLARE @SWV_cursor_var1    CURSOR

    SET @l_event_login = 1
    SET @l_event_logout = 7

    DELETE FROM agentids

    INSERT INTO agentids (filter, agentid)
        SELECT
             filter
            ,agentid
        FROM selected_agents sa
        WHERE sa.agentname = @p_agentname
        AND sa.agentloginid = @p_agentloginid;

    DELETE FROM temp_asdr1

    INSERT INTO temp_asdr1(agentid, eventtype, eventdatetime, reasoncode)
        SELECT
             asdr.agentid
            ,asdr.eventtype
            ,asdr.eventdatetime
            ,asdr.reasoncode
        FROM 
             agentstatedetail asdr
            ,agentids ai 
        WHERE asdr.agentid = ai.agentid 
        AND asdr.eventdatetime BETWEEN @p_startTime AND  @p_endTime 
        AND asdr.eventtype IN(@l_event_login,@l_event_logout)

    UPDATE temp_asdr1
        SET filter = (SELECT
                        filter
                      FROM agentids ai
        WHERE ai.agentid = temp_asdr1.agentid)

    DELETE FROM temp_asdr

    --alter sequence temp_asdr_seq 
    SELECT
         @l_mineventdatetime = min(eventdatetime)
        ,@l_maxeventdatetime = max(eventdatetime)
    FROM temp_asdr1
    WHERE filter = 1

    EXECUTE dbo.sp_executesql    'l_mineventdatetime'
                                ,@l_mineventdatetime

    EXECUTE dbo.sp_executesql    'l_maxeventdatetime'
                                ,@l_maxeventdatetime

    IF @@rowcount = 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT
             @l_mineventdatetime = NULL
            ,@l_maxeventdatetime = NULL
        EXECUTE dbo.sp_executesql   'l_mineventdatetime'
                                    ,@l_mineventdatetime
        EXECUTE dbo.sp_executesql    'l_maxeventdatetime'
                                    ,@l_maxeventdatetime
    END

    DELETE FROM temp_asdr1
    WHERE ((eventdatetime <= l_mineventdatetime)
        OR (eventdatetime >= @l_maxeventdatetime))
        AND filter = 0

    SET @SWV_cursor_var1 = CURSOR FOR
    SELECT
        agentid,
        eventtype,
        eventdatetime,
        reasoncode,
        filter
    FROM temp_asdr1
    ORDER BY eventdatetime
    OPEN @SWV_cursor_var1
    FETCH NEXT FROM @SWV_cursor_var1 INTO @l_agentid, @l_eventtype, @l_eventdatetime, @l_reasoncode, @l_filter
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        -- WARNING: The INSERT statement was commented, because column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.
        -- insert into temp_asdr(agentid, eventtype, eventdatetime, reasoncode, filter) values(temp_asdr_seq.nextval,l_agentid, l_eventtype, l_eventdatetime, l_reasoncode, l_filter);
        FETCH NEXT FROM @SWV_cursor_var1 INTO @l_agentid, @l_eventtype, @l_eventdatetime, @l_reasoncode, @l_filter
    END
    CLOSE @SWV_cursor_var1

    DELETE FROM temp_asdr1

    SELECT TOP 1
        @l_eventtype = eventtype,
        @l_eventdatetime = eventdatetime,
        @l_reasoncode = reasoncode,
        @l_filter = filter
    FROM temp_asdr
    WHERE eventdatetime = (SELECT
        MIN(eventdatetime)
    FROM temp_asdr) 

    IF @@rowcount = 0
        SELECT
            @l_eventtype = NULL,
            @l_eventdatetime = NULL,
            @l_reasoncode = NULL,
            @l_filter = NULL

    DELETE FROM temp_login_logout

    IF (@l_eventtype = @l_event_logout)
        INSERT INTO temp_login_logout (seq, logintime, op1, logouttime, reasoncode, loginfilter, logoutfilter)
            VALUES (0, NULL, '<', @l_eventdatetime, NULL, @l_filter, @l_filter)

    INSERT INTO temp_login_logout (seq, logintime, loginfilter)
        SELECT
            seq,
            eventdatetime,
            filter
        FROM temp_asdr tasdr
        WHERE eventtype = @l_event_login

    UPDATE temp_login_logout
    SET logouttime = (SELECT
                eventdatetime
            FROM temp_asdr tasdr
            WHERE tasdr.eventtype = @l_event_logout
            AND tasdr.seq = (temp_login_logout.seq + 1)),
            logoutfilter = (SELECT
                filter
            FROM temp_asdr tasdr
            WHERE tasdr.eventtype = @l_event_logout
            AND tasdr.seq = (temp_login_logout.seq + 1)),
            reasoncode = (SELECT
                reasoncode
            FROM temp_asdr tasdr
            WHERE tasdr.eventtype = @l_event_logout
            AND tasdr.seq = (temp_login_logout.seq + 1))

    UPDATE temp_login_logout
    SET logouttime = @p_endTime,
            op2 = '>',
            logoutfilter = 0
    WHERE logouttime IS NULL
    UPDATE temp_login_logout
    SET logintime = NULL,
            op1 = '<',
            reasoncode = NULL
    WHERE loginfilter = 0
    AND logoutfilter = 1
    UPDATE temp_login_logout
    SET logouttime = NULL,
            op2 = '>',
            reasoncode = NULL
    WHERE loginfilter = 1
    AND logoutfilter = 0
    DELETE FROM temp_login_logout
    WHERE loginfilter = 0
        AND logoutfilter = 0
    UPDATE temp_login_logout
    SET duration = dbo.datediff('ss', logintime, logouttime)
END
```

Can someone please help with this error.

Comment: what's the exact error message?. Does the `agentids` table actually has a `filter` column?

Comment: Yes it does. And all table mentioned here are Table variable created in a separate function. But i am getting error to the snippet which i have included. Saying **Invalid column name 'filter'**. If I remove that part and compile procedure, I can successfully do so.

Comment: Why are you using a cursor here? And you need to be careful as you have created a race condition on your persistent "temp" tables. If you have multiple users running this they are going to step all over each other. You should consider rewriting this as a set based approach instead of row by agonizing row.

Comment: Does it work if you bracket the word filter as [filter]

Comment: No, it does not.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, I have understood an issue with this.

May be its a glitch or something. But here what I did was deleted the function created where I had this table variable created. And then created the Stored Procedure first and then created function.

I was able to successfully compiled.